# Visual Studio wont show me an installed font

Tags: fonts, visual-studio

I want to take a specific font for my Windows Forms, but Visual Studio does not give me the option to select it. Other fonts, that are not installed default on Windows, are shown.

Ive tried re-opening VS, restarting the PC, deinstalling the font, closing Visual Studio and reinstalling the font when VS was closed, but nothing worked.

I can also find the font if I look into C:/Windows/Fonts.

Comment: What font? How did you install it? Is the font visible in other applications?

Comment: Pokémon Ruby & Sapphire font. The font does not appear in Libre Office, which might be a good hint.